# Binding a ViewModel directly to an Extended WPF Toolkit PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to bind a ViewModel directly to a PropertyGrid without the ViewModel having to contain a reference to itself. i.e at the moment I have:

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid SelectedObject="{Binding ViewModel}">
```

And in the ViewModel I have:

```
public class WatcherBaseViewModel : ObservableObject 
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    // Do I really need this?
    public WatcherBaseViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return this; }
    }

    // Rest of class removed for clarity
 }
```

Since this works it's all very academic but brevity being the soul of wit and all... Is there any way I can **directly** reference the ViewModel in a XAML binding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `Path` form binding since it will point to `DataContext` which already is `WatcherBaseViewModel`:

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid SelectedObject="{Binding}">
```

Comment: Yeah happens sometimes..!! :)